# Curl options equivalent to "useDefaultCredentials" by Net.Webclient

Tags: curl, webclient, php-curl

I try to access to the web with curl in a php script :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.fr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close ($ch);
```

It returns :

> Failed to connect to www.google.fr port 443: Connection refused

That's normal, I'm behind a proxy, which require my Windows credentials (NTLM) to allow internet trafic.

In MS Powershell, this works :

```
$request = New-Object System.Net.WebCLient
$request.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$request.Proxy.Credentials = $request.Credentials
$request.DownloadFile($url, $path)
```

Using the "DefaultCredentials" (= Windows Credentials) and send them to the proxy allows me to access to the web. But I don't now how it works.

If I navigate using Firefox, Firefox always add a **Proxy-Authorization** header, with value : **Negociate blablablablababalazdlad...**

I want to transpose the .NET useDefaultCredentials solution to cURL, I tried :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.fr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM );

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close ($ch);
```

Without success

Answer (score 2):

curl can do this if it was built with "**SSPI**" support enabled. You can normally run `curl -V` on a prompt to check that. or `php -i` or invoke `phpinfo();` from within PHP itself.

### With SSPI

You set the `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD` option to a blank user/passwd (in addition to the other options) just to trigger authentication, but it will then get the default credentials for you:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, ":" );
```

The full code would then look something like this below. Note also that `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` is for authentication to the remote server, not the proxy. And I figure it unlikely you actually want HTTP auth with google...

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.fr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://proxyhost.example.com:8080/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, ":" );

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close ($ch);
```

### Without SSPI

Then curl can't figure out the default credentials but instead you *must* set the user name and password with the `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD` option, like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "clark%20kent:superman");
```

Comment: My `phpinfo();` says SSPI: Yes, and I already tried ":" as USERPWD on both PROXY and HTTP. I always get the same error Connection refused

Comment: Then you forgot to point out the proxy (`CURLOPT_PROXY`) so it tries to access the remote server directly. curl can't figure that out itself...

Comment: How can I find the proxy URL ? If I use firebug to show the content of a succeed request I only se a "Proxy-Authorization" header with value "Negociate %big_key%"

Comment: That header is used in a header sent to the proxy. I presume Firebug can tell you which host/machine that receives that header. That is the proxy.

Comment: I am till searching a way to find out the proxy name. Nothing in firebux, nothing in IE developper tools.

Answer (score 2):

> I try to access to the web with curl in a php script :
>   **https://www.google.fr**

The problem is that google content is served over ssl i.e https:  I've modified your code to allow https connection:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.fr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close ($ch);

print_r( $result );
```

Using HTTP NTLM Authentication | CURLAUTH_NTLM

*HTTP NTLM authentication. A proprietary protocol invented and used by Microsoft. It uses a challenge-response and hash concept similar to Digest, to prevent the password from being eavesdropped.*

You need to build libcurl with either **OpenSSL**, **GnuTLS** or **NSS** *support for this option to work, or build libcurl on Windows with SSPI support.*

Let's put this into a simple function.

```
function Auth($username, $password, $endpoint)
{
    $username = ( isset( $username ) && !empty($username) ) ? trim( $username ) : '';
    $password = ( isset( $password ) && !empty($password) ) ? trim( $password ) : '';
    $proxy_address = "local.domain.com:1024";


    $ch = curl_init();

    if($ch)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint );  
            /* make use of proxy */
            curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_address );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            /* Allow ANY Auth */
            curl_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY );

            /* Set credentials or leave empty to prompt */
            curl_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "$username:$password" );

            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
            }   

            curl_close($ch);
        }
}
```

Usage: Auth("username", "yourPassWord", "http://local.domain.com:1080/");

**Let others know if this helps you**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No it doesn't change anything. And I already tested it with http / 80 website, I have the same problem.

Comment: @Alsatian I just tested the above code it works like charm.  What error are you getting if any ?  You can test the same code here http://www.vegasnewspaper.com/stack/test.php

Comment: You didn't understand the question, it's about using windows credentials to authentificate on a proxy.